# windows phone 8 highlight colors in input fields

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

in internet explorer 10 (mobile version), a selectbox () gets highlighted blue as soon as it gets focused, (it´s the blue of the whole Modern UI surface of the phone). the styles for the select tag:

```
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
font-size: 14px;
height: 25px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
float: left;
font-weight: 400;
padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
background-origin: content-box, content-box;
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
background-size: 11px 6px, 1px 160px;
background-position: right center, 0 -1px;
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABcAAAAMAQMAAACz9bS7AAAABlBMV…vQuZgJjsYojkBJQf75i4cGzcXt5HJQ/Djs7L5sApGeVNPJDzbGEbOb/85rAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC), url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAlgCAIAAADGR8ryAAACZ0lEQ…tDzV5P+JnOAzg9qR2Xlg+a8jAvtyK/P5fSI6Sf3c3NhwADAJ0Rj8qbukvYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
```

I was hoping the "-ms-user-select: none" would fix it, but didnt.. Has anyone experience similar?

Comment: Do you mean the whole element gets highlighted, or just a focus ring around the element? If the former, <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/> should work. If the latter, it is probably possible to remove it with select:focus { outline: none; } but I don't have a device to test right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered a similar problem on WP7 an WP8, the solution is to move focus from select box to fake input on click event.

jQuery:

```
$('select').on('click', function() {
    $('input.fakeInput').focus().blur()
})
```

CSS:

```
.fakeInput {
    display: block;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    top: -999rem;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Note: do not forget to add this code only for mobile device, on desktop browsers it will work not as expected.

Comment: I just want to add that it doesnt work on a Samsung Galaxy S3 anymore. The .blur() immediatly closes android`s native select dropdown menu after clicking the select tag.

Answer (score 1):

IE has its own CSS pseudo-element to deal with this highlight.

CSS:

```
select::-ms-value{ background-color: transparent; color: black; }
```

You may read more about this on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

it´s interesting but since I add this line to my style sheet, it keeps highlighting blue, but doesn´t stay that way after you select something from the selectbox.

Thought I add it as an answer if somebody comes back with the issue.

```
:focus{outline: none;}
```