# A blue highlight on dropdown box when select any value in windows phone 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cordova

Working on a windows phone 8 app in Phonegap. When I touch the dropdown box a blue highlight will appear.
I gone through the question already asked here

[**windows phone 8 highlight colors in input fields**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105084/windows-phone-8-highlight-colors-in-input-fields)

tried the answer

`$('select').on('click', function() {
    $('input.fakeInput').focus().blur()
})`

it solved the issue partially (only on click event). But my page has scroll, so when I try to scroll, the blue highlight is appearing again. I tried 'MSPointerDown, MSPointerUp, MSPointerMove' in the above code, but nothing happened.

[image]

Here are the styles I used

```
{
width: 100%;
background: #fafafa;
color:#a3a3a3;
font-size:14px;
border:none;
outline:none;
display: inline-block;
appearance:none;
height:60%;
min-height: 30px !important;
border-radius:5px;
margin-top: 5%;
padding-left:8%;
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE has a pseudo class that overwrites this

```
select::-ms-value{ background-color: #fafafa; color: #a3a3a3; }
```

this solves it

link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465820.aspx